# Tkinter Auto Running command in a menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this following menu created in Tkinter

```
subMenu = Menu(Selection)
Selection.add_cascade(label = "Maze Generation Algorithms", menu = subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label = "Recursive Back Tracking", command = FindNext(Stack[0], Stack, canvas, root))
```

The problem is when I start up my program, the FindNext function will automatically run without the menu button being pressed yet. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lambda

---

```
subMenu.add_command(label = "Recursive Back Tracking", command = lambda:FindNext(Stack[0], Stack, canvas, root))
```